# How to separate logic and GUI

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a program to build and solve a Maze using DFS and backtracking using Java Swing. The code was a mess when I have to put my logic into my JPanel in order to show animation via the call to `repaint()`. Here are all classes:

**Point**

```
public class Point {
    public int mX;
    public int mY;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }
}
```

**Turtle**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;


public class Turtle {
    private int mXPos;
    private int mYPos;
    private Color mColor;

    public Turtle(Color c) {
        mXPos = 0;
        mYPos = 0;
        mColor = c;
    }

    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        mXPos = x;
        mYPos = y;
    }

    public int getXPos() {
        return mXPos;
    }

    public int getYPos() {
        return mYPos;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        int width = 15;
        int height = 18;
        int heading = 0;
        int xPos = mXPos;
        int yPos = mYPos;

        // cast to 2d object
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        // save the current transformation
        AffineTransform oldTransform = g2.getTransform();

        // rotate the turtle and translate to xPos and yPos
        g2.rotate(Math.toRadians(heading),xPos,yPos);

        // determine the half width and height of the shell
        int halfWidth = (int) (width/2);        // of shell
        int halfHeight = (int) (height/2);      // of shell
        int quarterWidth = (int) (width/4);     // of shell
        int thirdHeight = (int) (height/3);     // of shell
        int thirdWidth = (int) (width/3);       // of shell

          // draw the body parts (head)
        g2.setColor(mColor);
        g2.fillOval(xPos - quarterWidth, yPos - halfHeight - (int) (height/3), halfWidth, thirdHeight);
        g2.fillOval(xPos - (2 * thirdWidth), yPos - thirdHeight, thirdWidth, thirdHeight);
        g2.fillOval(xPos - (int) (1.6 * thirdWidth), yPos + thirdHeight, thirdWidth, thirdHeight);
        g2.fillOval(xPos + (int) (1.3 * thirdWidth), yPos - thirdHeight, thirdWidth, thirdHeight);
        g2.fillOval(xPos + (int) (0.9 * thirdWidth), yPos + thirdHeight, thirdWidth, thirdHeight);

        // draw the shell
        g2.setColor(mColor);
        g2.fillOval(xPos - halfWidth, yPos - halfHeight, width, height);
        // reset the transformation matrix
        g2.setTransform(oldTransform);
    }

}
```

**MazeBuilder**

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPanel;


public class MazeBuilder extends JPanel {
    /*
     * Maze row
     */
    private static int ROW = 15;

    /*
     * Maze Column
     */
    private static int COLUMN = 15;

    /*
     * Number of vertices
     */
    private static int VERTICES = ROW * COLUMN;

    /*
     * Length of edge
     */
    private static int SPACING = 40;

    /*
     * Spacing from the top left corner (0, 0)
     */
    private static int SHIFTING = 50;

    /*
     * The goal is at the lower right corner
     */
    private int mGoalVertex = VERTICES - 1;

    /*
     * The marked drawing map
     */
    private boolean[][] mMap = new boolean[VERTICES][VERTICES];

    /*
     * Vertex information
     *      if mExplored[u] == true
     *          vertex u is already visited 
     */
    private boolean[] mExplored = new boolean[VERTICES];

    /*
     * Vertex information for solver
     *      if mExplored[u] == true
     *          vertex u is already visited 
     */
    private boolean[] mTurtleExplored = new boolean[VERTICES];

    /*
     * The waiting time for repaint
     */
    private static int BUILD_TIME = 5;

    /*
     * Delay time
     */
    private static int SOLVE_TIME = 500;

    /*
     * Parent frame
     */
    private JFrame mFrame;

    /*
     * Random generator
     */
    private Random mRandom;

    /*
     * Current position of turtle
     */
    private int mCurrentVertex = 0;

    /*
     * Solve mode
     */
    private boolean flag = false;


    /*
     * Flag variable to signify the 
     * maze have been completely built
     */
    private boolean isCompletelyBuilt = false;

    /*
     * The turtle for maze solver
     */
    private Turtle mSolver;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param frame
     *          the parent frame
     */
    public MazeBuilder(JFrame frame) {
        mFrame = frame;     
        // initialize random
        mRandom = new Random();

        mSolver = new Turtle(Color.red);

        initGraph();
        initExplored();
        buildMenu(mFrame);
    }

    /**
     * Delay for an amount of time
     * before redraw the panel
     */
    private void delay(int delayTime) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(delayTime);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.err.println("Error in delay");
        }
    }

    private boolean noMoreVertices() {
        for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES; ++i) {
            if (mTurtleExplored[i] == false)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void solveMazeBacktracking(int u) {
        mCurrentVertex = u;
        if (u == mGoalVertex || noMoreVertices()) {
            flag = false;
            return;
        }

        mTurtleExplored[u] = true;

        // for each neighbor of u make a move
        List<Integer> neighbors = getTurtleNeighbors(u);
        for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); ++i) {
            int v = neighbors.get(i);
            if (mMap[u][v] == true || mMap[v][u] == true) {
                delay(SOLVE_TIME);
                repaint();
                solveMazeBacktracking(v);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Build the menu bar and add
     * it to frame f
     * 
     * @param f
     *          frame to hold menu bar
     */
    public void buildMenu(JFrame f) {
        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
        JMenu optionMenu = new JMenu("Option");
        JMenuItem item;
        item = new JMenuItem("Solve");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                flag = true;
                (new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        solveMazeBacktracking(0);
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        });
        optionMenu.add(item);

        item = new JMenuItem("Build");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // repaint();
                (new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        buildMazeDfs(0);
                    }
                }).start();

            }
        });
        optionMenu.add(item);

        item = new JMenuItem("Reset");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (isCompletelyBuilt) {
                    isCompletelyBuilt = false;
                    resetMaze();
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
        optionMenu.add(item);

        bar.add(optionMenu);
        f.setJMenuBar(bar);
    }

    /**
     * Check if a square is in a maze
     *
     * @param x
     *          the x coordinate in JPanel
     * @param y
     *          the y coordinate in JPanel
     *
     * @return  
     *          true if it's in maze
     *          false otherwise
     */
    private boolean isInMaze(int x, int y) {
        return (x >= 0 && x < ROW && y >= 0 && y < COLUMN);
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of neighbors of a vertex 
     * 
     * @param u
     *      vertex
     * 
     * @return neighbors
     *      an array list of int    
     */
    private List<Integer> getTurtleNeighbors(int u) {
        List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Point p = toPoint(u);
        int to = -1;

        // up
        if (isInMaze(p.mX - 1, p.mY)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX - 1, p.mY);
            if (!mTurtleExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // down 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX + 1, p.mY)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX + 1, p.mY);
            if (!mTurtleExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // left 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX,  p.mY - 1)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX, p.mY - 1);
            if (!mTurtleExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // right 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX, p.mY + 1)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX, p.mY + 1);
            if (!mTurtleExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        return neighbors;
    }

    /**
     * Get the number of neighbors of a vertex 
     * 
     * @param u
     *      vertex
     * 
     * @return neighbors
     *      vertex neighbor of u
     */
    private List<Integer> getNeighbors(int u) {
        List<Integer> neighbors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Point p = toPoint(u);
        int to = -1;

        // up
        if (isInMaze(p.mX - 1, p.mY)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX - 1, p.mY);
            if (!mExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // down 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX + 1, p.mY)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX + 1, p.mY);
            if (!mExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // left 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX,  p.mY - 1)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX, p.mY - 1);
            if (!mExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        // right 
        if (isInMaze(p.mX, p.mY + 1)) {
            to = toVertex(p.mX, p.mY + 1);
            if (!mExplored[to])
                neighbors.add(to);
        }

        return neighbors;
    }

    /**
     * DFS algorithm to remove edges
     *
     * @param u
     *      starting vertex
     *  
     */
    private void buildMazeDfs(int u) {
        // mark that vertex as visited
        mExplored[u] = true;

        // get all neighbors
        List<Integer> neighbors = getNeighbors(u);

        int v = -1;
        // get a random vertex v
        if (neighbors.size() > 0) {
            int idx = mRandom.nextInt(neighbors.size());
            v = neighbors.get(idx);
        }

        if (v == -1) {
            System.out.println("Backtrack");
            repaint();
            isCompletelyBuilt = true;
            return; 
        }

        // remove edge from u to v
        mMap[u][v] = true;
        mMap[v][u] = true;

        // loop through all u's neighbors 
        for (int n = 0; n < neighbors.size(); ++n) {
            // get the next neighbor
            int next = neighbors.get(n);
            // if it's not explored
            if (mExplored[next] == false) {
                // delay(BUILD_TIME);
                // repaint();
                buildMazeDfs(next);
            }
        }       
    }

    /**
     * Initialize vertices
     *      false: unexplored
     *      true: explored
     */
    private void initExplored() {
        for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES; ++i) { 
            mExplored[i] = false;
            mTurtleExplored[i] = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Initialize all marked to true:
     *      if mGraph[x][y] = true then 
     *          draw a line from x -> y
     *
     *      neighbor coordinates
     *      -------------------------------------
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      |           | (x-1, y)  |           |           
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      -------------------------------------
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      | (x, y-1)  | (x, y)    | (x, y+1)  |           
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      -------------------------------------
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      |           | (x+1, y)  |           |           
     *      |           |           |           |
     *      -------------------------------------
     *
     */
    private void initGraph() {
        // initialize all marked to false
        int vertices = ROW * COLUMN;
        for (int u = 0; u < vertices; ++u) {
            for (int v = 0; v < vertices; ++v) {
                mMap[u][v] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Convert a coordinate (x, y) to a vertex on graph
     *
     *          -------------
     *          | 0 | 1 | 2 |
     *          -------------
     *          | 3 | 4 | 5 |
     *          -------------
     *          | 6 | 7 | 8 |
     *          -------------
     *
     *          1) formula: 
     *              --------------------------
     *              -  vertex = x * ROW + y  -
     *              --------------------------
     *
     *          2) check:
     *          ROW = 3, COLUMN = 3
     *          then    
     *          [0][0] = 0 * 3 + 0 = 0
     *          [0][1] = 0 * 3 + 1 = 1
     *          [0][2] = 0 * 3 + 2 = 2
     *
     *          [1][0] = 1 * 3 + 0 = 3
     *          [1][1] = 1 * 3 + 1 = 4
     *          [1][2] = 1 * 3 + 2 = 5
     *
     *          [2][0] = 2 * 3 + 0 = 6
     *          [2][1] = 2 * 3 + 1 = 7
     *          [2][2] = 2 * 3 + 2 = 8
     *
     * @param x
     *          x coordinate
     * @param y 
     *          y coordinate
     * 
     * @return 
     *      a vertex
     *
     */
    private int toVertex(int x, int y) {
        return (x * ROW + y);
    }

    /**
     * Convert from a vertex v to a pair (x, y)
     *
     *          1) formula: 
     *              -----------------
     *              -  x = v / ROW  -
     *              -  y = v % ROW  -
     *              -----------------
     *
     *          2) check:
     *              0 and [0][0]
     *                  x = 0 / 3 = 0
     *                  y = 0 % 3 = 0
     *
     *              1 and [0][1]
     *                  x = 0 / 3 = 0
     *                  y = 1 % 3 = 1
     *
     *              6 and [2][0]
     *                  x = 6 / 3 = 2
     *                  y = 0 % 3 = 0
     *
     *              8 and [0][1]
     *                  x = 8 / 3 = 2
     *                  y = 8 % 3 = 2
     *
     *  @param v
     *          vertex
     *
     *  @return
     *          a point 
     */
    private Point toPoint(int v) {
        return new Point(v / ROW, v % COLUMN);
    }

    private void resetMaze() {
        initGraph();
        initExplored();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g;      
        g2D.setStroke(new BasicStroke(3f));
        g.setColor(Color.black);

        for (int x = 0; x < ROW; ++x) {
            for (int y = 0; y < COLUMN; ++y) {
                Point p = new Point(x, y);
                drawAPoint(g, p);
            }
        }

        // for each vertex u, we check its 4 neighbors
        int left;
        int right;
        int up;
        int down;

        Point from;
        Point to;

        for (int u = 0; u < VERTICES; ++u) {
            int c = u % COLUMN;
            int r = u / ROW;

            left  = -1;
            right = -1;
            up    = -1;
            down  = -1;

            from = toPoint(u);

            // left
            if (c - 1 >= 0) {
                left = r * ROW + c - 1;
            }

            // right
            if (c + 1 <= COLUMN - 1) {
                right = r * ROW + c + 1;
            }

            // down
            if (r - 1 >= 0) {
                down = (r - 1) * ROW + c;
            }

            // up
            if (r + 1 <= ROW - 1) {
                up = (r + 1) * ROW + c;
            }

            if (left != -1) {
                to = toPoint(left);
                if (mMap[u][left]) 
                    drawRemoveEdge(g, from, to);
            }

            if (right != -1) {
                to = toPoint(right);
                if (mMap[u][right]) 
                    drawRemoveEdge(g, from, to);
            }

            if (up != -1) {
                to = toPoint(up);
                if (mMap[u][up]) 
                    drawRemoveEdge(g, from, to);
            }

            if (down != -1) {
                to = toPoint(down);
                if (mMap[u][down]) 
                    drawRemoveEdge(g, from, to);
            }
            // delay(BUILD_TIME);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES; ++i) {
            if (mExplored[i]) {
                Point p = toPoint(i);
                g.setColor(Color.red);
                g.drawOval(p.mX * SPACING + 17 + SHIFTING, p.mY * SPACING +  17 + SHIFTING, 2, 2);
            }
        }

        if (flag) {
            Point p = toPoint(mCurrentVertex);
            mSolver.setPosition(p.mX * SPACING + 17 + SHIFTING, p.mY * SPACING + 17 + SHIFTING);
            mSolver.draw(g);

            for (int i = 0; i < VERTICES; ++i) {
                if (mTurtleExplored[i]) {
                    Point pp = toPoint(i);
                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    g.drawOval(pp.mX * SPACING + 17 + SHIFTING, pp.mY * SPACING + 17 + SHIFTING, 2, 2);
                }
            }
        }

        // this is the only way out
        Color c = Color.decode("#EEEEEE");
        g.setColor(c);
        Point p = new Point((ROW - 1)* SPACING + SHIFTING, (COLUMN - 1) * SPACING + SHIFTING); 
        g.drawLine(p.mX + SPACING, p.mY, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY + SPACING);
    }

    /**
     * Remove an edge from to point
     * 
     * @param g
     *          graphics component
     * 
     * @param cur
     *          the current vertex
     * 
     * @param adj
     *          its neighbor
     */
    private void drawRemoveEdge(Graphics g, Point cur, Point adj) {
        Color c = Color.decode("#EEEEEE");
        g.setColor(c);
        Point p = new Point(cur.mX * SPACING + SHIFTING, cur.mY * SPACING + SHIFTING); 
        // right
        if (cur.mX + 1 == adj.mX && cur.mY == adj.mY) {
            g.drawLine(p.mX + SPACING, p.mY, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY + SPACING);
        }
        // left
        else if (cur.mX - 1 == adj.mX && cur.mY == adj.mY) {
            g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY, p.mX, p.mY + SPACING);
        }
        // top
        else if (cur.mX == adj.mX && cur.mY - 1 == adj.mY) {
            g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY);
        }
        else if (cur.mX == adj.mX && cur.mY + 1 == adj.mY){
            g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY + SPACING, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY + SPACING);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Draw a box around one point
     * 
     * @param g
     *          graphics component
     * 
     * @param p
     *          the point to be drawn
     */
    private void drawAPoint(Graphics g, Point p) {
        // add spacing
        p.mX = p.mX * SPACING + SHIFTING;
        p.mY = p.mY * SPACING + SHIFTING;

        // draw top
        g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY);
        // draw left
        g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY, p.mX, p.mY + SPACING);
        // draw right
        g.drawLine(p.mX + SPACING, p.mY, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY + SPACING);
        // draw bottom
        g.drawLine(p.mX, p.mY + SPACING, p.mX + SPACING, p.mY + SPACING);
    }

    /**
     * Build entire UI
     */
    public static void buildGUI() {
        // create a container level JFrame
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Maze Generator");

        // set up frame
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        // create a panel
        MazeBuilder app = new MazeBuilder(frame);
        app.buildMenu(frame);
        frame.setContentPane(app);

    }
}
```

**Program**

```
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Program {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // run on event-dispatching thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MazeBuilder.buildGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I knew it was very bad when putting the logic of maze into the UI class, but I couldn't find a way to extract them out. Please help criticizing my code. Thanks.

Comment: Why did you create your own `Point` class? [Java already has one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) which looks identical to yours, except with some additional functionality. I would also either use or extend from it in the `Turtle` class.

Comment: I'm newbie to Swing and Java, so I was not aware of that class. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few tips:

- When I ran you program at first, I got a blank frame. Make sure `frame.setVisible(true)` is the last thing you do. Everything else should be set up before that.
- Really, really, really avoid magic numbers. Code like this:

  ```
  public void draw(Graphics g) {
      int width = 15;
      int height = 18;
      // etc.
  }
  ```

  Is really hard to maintain. You have a few constants. Just add more.
- Swing uses swing Timer and SwingWorker rather than threads. For example,

  ```
  private class MazeSolvingWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Boolean[][]> {

      // Stores its own copy of the map
      private Boolean[][] map_;

      // Needs to get map from main program
      public MazeSolvingWorker(Boolean[][] map) {
          map_ = map;
      }

      // This function replaces the run method
      @Override
      protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
          solveMazeBacktracking(0);
          return null;
      }

      // Need to override when you use publish
      @Override
      protected void process(List<Boolean[][]> chunks) {
          mMap = chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1);
          repaint();
      }

      private void solveMazeBacktracking(int u) {
          mCurrentVertex = u;
          if (u == mGoalVertex || noMoreVertices()) {
              flag = false;
              return;
          }

          mTurtleExplored[u] = true;

          // for each neighbor of u make a move
          List<Integer> neighbors = getTurtleNeighbors(u);
          for (int i = 0; i < neighbors.size(); ++i) {
              int v = neighbors.get(i);
              if (map_[u][v] == true || map_[v][u] == true) {
                  delay(SOLVE_TIME);
                  // Thread-safe alternative to calling repaint directly
                  publish(map_);
                  solveMazeBacktracking(v);
              }
          }
      }

  }
  ```

  Now you can replace this:

  ```
  item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          flag = true;
          (new Thread() {
              public void run() {
                  solveMazeBacktracking(0);
              }
          }).start();
      }
  });
  ```

  with this:

  ```
  item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
          flag = true;
          new MazeSolvingWorker(mMap).execute();
      }
  });
  ```

  Replacing buildMazeDfs(int) is up to you.
- Normally, I would recommend using the [entity-system framework](http://piemaster.net/2011/07/entity-component-artemis/) to separate logic from data and ui, but you have a very simple program. Factor out a Maze class.
- This is just nit-picky, but you don't need a static method in `MazeBuilder` to build the gui. You can move that to `Program`, where it makes more sense. Or you could get rid of the `Program` class and put main in `MazeBuilder`. Just a style preference though. :)